# When using yolov7 pose,the size of the generated image is smaller than the original,how to fix?

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5, openpose

I referenced the code from this [link](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/tools/keypoint.ipynb).

```
import torch
import cv2
from torchvision import transforms
import numpy as np
from utils.datasets import letterbox
from utils.general import non_max_suppression_kpt
from utils.plots import output_to_keypoint, plot_skeleton_kpts

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
weigths = torch.load('weights/yolov7-w6-pose.pt', map_location=device)
model = weigths['model']
_ = model.float().eval()

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.half().to(device)

image = cv2.imread('image/zidane.jpg')
image = letterbox(image, 960, stride=64, auto=True)[0]
image_ = image.copy()
image = transforms.ToTensor()(image)
image = torch.tensor(np.array([image.numpy()]))

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    image = image.half().to(device)
output, _ = model(image)

output = non_max_suppression_kpt(output, 0.25, 0.65, nc=model.yaml['nc'], nkpt=model.yaml['nkpt'], kpt_label=True)
with torch.no_grad():
    output = output_to_keypoint(output)
nimg = image[0].permute(1, 2, 0) * 255
nimg = nimg.cpu().numpy().astype(np.uint8)
nimg = cv2.cvtColor(nimg, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
for idx in range(output.shape[0]):
    plot_skeleton_kpts(nimg, output[idx, 7:].T, 3)
nimg2 = cv2.cvtColor(nimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imwrite('E:/result.jpg',nimg2 )
```

The size of my original image `zidane.jpg` is 1280X720,the size of the image `result.jpg` is 970X576.

How can I not change the size of the generated image `result.jpg`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically a deep learning model takes an input of a fixed size. Fortunately YOLO is by nature a full convolutional model and so should be able to take a flexible size in input (with predictions considering the same size). In your code the function `letterbox` resizes your image (see [here](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/utils/datasets.py#L984) the code). You can then try to change the size `960` to `(1280, 720)`.

Comment: I change my code:`image = letterbox(image,new_shape=image.shape[1],stride=64,auto=True)[0]` 
The height of the generated image is 768, which is a multiple of 32. The size of the image generated by convolution is a multiple of 32, so the size of the generated image will be different.I try `image = letterbox(image,new_shape=image.shape[1],stride=32,auto=True)[0]`,but the error message is:`RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Got 24 and 23 (The offending index is 0)`.I don't know why.But stride=64 or stride=128 is OK.